# Can't play this video in android

Tags: android

I have tested my application in so many devices the video is playing but in 'OppoR7plusf' it shows can't play this video. please suggest me what should i do now.
I am using:

```
VideoView vidHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideo);
vidHolder.setMinimumHeight(1000);
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo);
vidHolder.setVideoURI(video);
vidHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        jump();
    }
});
vidHolder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st way**

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo);
```

Change to

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/myvideo");
```

---

**2nd way** `getActivity()` if you are in fragment other wise `ActivityName.this`

```
 int id = getResources().getIdentifier("myvideo", "raw", getActivity().getPackageName());
 String path = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + id;
 Uri.parse(path)
```

Comment: I tried both the way but its not working.. sorry! any other help!